# How to add an Outlook add-in for Office 365 2016 using PowerShell or CMD?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in for Office 365 (https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted), but I have to create a Script with PowerShell or CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to install outlook addins through scripting, please take a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218722(v=exchg.160).aspx

In particular, you can use -FileData (to install your manifest from file) or -Url (to install from a Url that points to your manifest).

For a enterprise wide deployment, you should definitely look at install it as an organization addin (using -OrganizationApp in powershell or EAC), so that the addin is available for all users.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943752(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this tomorrow but is this the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You question is very vague...

First, an add-in is simply a web page inserted in Office host with a library (Office.js) that enable your web app to communicate with Office host.

Having said that there is no way for you to execute Powershell script or CMD within the browser or the add-in.

However, you can easily execute the script from the server code that serves your add-in.

If you want to execute CMD or Powershell scripts which are Microsoft based script it will be easier using a webserver technology like ASP.NET (MVC or Web API).

To execute Powershell script easily within a .NET process have a look at *System.Management.Automation*

Comment: Nope, I have an app (a simple web page) this works fine, but now my client says: "Ok, now deploy on 9500 machines of my own enterprise via Active Directory", I supose that Outlook have any way to install this add-in via Powershell or CMD and deploy this script to 9500 machines.

Comment: Your question is terribly ill posed. You do not want your addin to execute a powershell script but to deploy an addin entreprise wide. Update your question and i will upfate my answer.